# SQL Query Related to chat system (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do not understand how this sql query work. Can anyone explain to me? thank you !!

```
$req1 = mysql_query('
  SELECT 
    m1.id, 
    m1.title, 
    m1.timestamp, 
    count(m2.id) as reps, 
    users.id as userid, 
    users.username 
  FROM 
    pm as m1, pm as m2, users 
  WHERE ((m1.user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user1read="no" and users.id=m1.user2) 
          or (m1.user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and m1.user2read="no" and users.id=m1.user1)) 
         and m1.id2="1" and m2.id=m1.id 
  GROUP BY m1.id 
  ORDER BY m1.id desc
');
```

There are two tables which i used.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user1read` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `user2read` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: it is related to a chat system.

Comment: Explicit join syntax would be of help. The query would be better readable.

Comment: Please edit your CREATE TABLE statements into your question.

Comment: $_SESSION['userid'] ------> where do this userid come from ? =(

Comment: i will get this error when i run 

Notice: Undefined index: userid in

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if we write it out like this...?

```
 SELECT m1.id
      , m1.title
      , m1.timestamp
      , COUNT(m2.id) reps
      , u.id userid
      , u.username 
   FROM pm m1
   JOIN pm m2
     ON m2.id = m1.id 
   JOIN users u
     ON u.id = m1.user1 
  WHERE (
           (m1.user1 = $_SESSION['userid'] AND m1.user1read = 'no')  
        OR (m1.user2 = $_SESSION['userid'] AND m1.user2read = 'no')
        )
    AND m1.id2 = 1
  GROUP BY m1.id 
  ORDER BY m1.id DESC
```

Comment: erm so it only uses one table which is pm ?

Comment: Eh? How do you get that? It uses two instances of one table, and one instance of another table.

Comment: Strawberry , if i am not wrong , the sql query is using both users and pm table ?